# Is there any way to achieve a network fault-tolerant print server?

Tags: windows, cluster

Our infrastructure is actually  composed by a main datacenter in headquarters, where are centralized almost all of the services and aplications, and a smaller datacenter, in a building accross the city, connected by fiber, with services and aplications related to this location. Also, we've a bunch of locations in the city, connected by WLAN or dsl.

In case of network interconection failure that may get isolated any of the principal offices, or the main datacenter going down, we need certain services, actually being provided only by the main datacenter, like the print server, still being available locally.

So we wonder if it's possible, (with windows), to have a main print server living in our main datacenter, and one computer in the other offices that keeps in sync with the main print server, and when it becomes unreachable, takes its job transparently to the user (without need to change the shared printer mapping in the user computer, let's say, we've a shared printer named \srv-printers\printer1 , and that should work no matter what server is doing the job.

I googled it, and seen about windows failover clusters, but don't seems to be exactly what we want to do, first seems that failover clusters need to be physically connected (in our case the machines would be at some miles away), and seems oriented to be only one machine doing the job at a time, we need that in normal operation, that be only one machine doing the job (for print accounting purposes) and in case of a network problem (WAN), the machine that cannot reach the master server, work simultaneously but isolated, and when things get fixed, return to his pasive role without any pain.

we're asking to much just to keep things centralised? If it works with print server,we will consider doing the same with other services.

Comment: Print server is just a server which queues as job. Thus you can use dns round robin, or have virtual IP with load balancer.

Comment: I would say you should have services which are crucial to you as close as possible. Thus I would put print server in each office. Wouldn't be possible to have remote printers displayed as fake local printers server by local print server? If remote print server serving remote printers would go down, local print server would keep jobs. SPOF is local print server here but it's easier to reboot/repair local print server then remote one :)

Comment: Jiri, we don't want load balacing. In normal conditions, all jobs must go to the main datacenter, ideally. Also, its vital that headquarters and secondary datacenter office can work flawless if the other goes offline. This include printing at the moment.

Comment: Load balancing can do checking first. Local print server -> main DC. If main DC down -> secondary DC. If secondary DC down -> keep locally.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to 3rd party print server solutions, you are looking at a geographically dispersed clustering.  However, that usually requires expensive storage subsystems and therefore probably not the best candidate for your mixed hub/spoke topology.  If you had two DCs, one of which was primary and the other secondary, you could deploy such a configuration and have a print server clustered between the DCs, spooling jobs for printers within each office.  Although in this case, if one of the offices went offline totally, it won't be able to print at all.

Alternatively you could put a stand-alone Windows print server in each office and periodically pull accounting stats from its event logs using any number of pre-baked scripts people have already written for this exact purpose.

Depending on your printer capabilities, you may have accounting capability already in the firmware and could just pull stats from there, without requiring a Windows server at each of your offices.

Or you could investigate 3rd party solutions as mentioned before.  Anyway, hope this helps you pick a solution, which bets suits your needs and budget.

-- ab1

Comment: Actually we've three DC, two at headquarters, and one in secondary datacenter. We're considering putting another more in other office due to poor network connection (WLAN). These are the  most vital places that should work. All other servers (+75), including print server, are virtualized (vmware) in the two datacenters (but not replicated, each vm can live only in one of the datacenters at a time). Also, we've a fully replicated SAN solution (active-active) between the two datacenters.

Comment: I will search about"geographically dispersed clustering", as seems promising. Maybe in-sync active-active clustering could do the trick, if the accounting soft can handle it. But.. after a long period of being "working in its own" all of them, after a network problem, may it "resync" easily?

Comment: A single clustered resource, such as a print server or a database instance lives on just one of the cluster nodes and moves to another node in case of an issue, carrying with it all of its resources, settings, etc. (hence the need for shared storage).  If you want to have some kind of active-active print server config, you could try setting up two print server instances in your geographically dispersed cluster, put a load-balancer in front of the clustered IPs and direct your print clients to the LB VIP.  Not sure if this is supported, but some people have mentioned it as a potential solution.